# CodeIgniter: Form Validation good practice

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a project with Parse + CodeIgniter.
I have two screens to manage ParseUsers: allUsers.php, that list all users.
And detailUser.php, that create/edit a user.

When user submit a form (new ParseUser), i call save method. That contains the code:

```
try{

                if ($user_id)
                    $user->save(true); // Update
                else
                    $user->signUp(); // Insert

                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success');
                redirect('all-users');              
            }
            catch(Parse\ParseException $error){
                $error_message = $error->getMessage();
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error: ' . $error_message); 
                $this->data['user'] = $user;
                $this->view = 'user/userDetail';
            }
```

And at view, I have this (example user's name):

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required value="<?php if(isset($user)): echo $user->name; endif;?>">
```

The form maintain the fields filled correctly, but the flashdata it's empty, if I refresh the page, than the flashdata appears.
So, I after a search I found people saying that flashdata just works with redirect.

If I redirect my page, the flashdata appears. But, the fields are not filled.

I read about set_value, that is the correct way to maintain the fields? But, I like to have just two views, one to list all and another create/edit users. So, if I use the set_value, this is possible?
What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

use load instead of redirect

```
        try{

            if ($user_id)
                $user->save(true); // Update
            else
                $user->signUp(); // Insert

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success');
            $this->load->view('path');//use load instead of redirect              
        }
        catch(Parse\ParseException $error){
            $error_message = $error->getMessage();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error: ' . $error_message); 
            $this->data['user'] = $user;
            $this->view = 'user/userDetail';
        }
```